# two activities app crashes when changing layout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have run into a problem, when trying to change the layout after receiving an intent in my mainActivity. I have two classes

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

    //two Intents are received
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("message"))
        { //another intent is received (works fine)}
    if(extras.containsKey("scanContent")) {
            Log.e(TAG, "scancontent intent received"); 
            String msg = extras.getString("scanContent");
            Log.e(TAG, msg); 
            arrowS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//app is refreshed, but nothing is changed
                        }

  scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent scan = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scan.class);
            startActivity(scan);
        } } });}
```

Scan class:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            Intent i = new Intent(Scan.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("scanContent", contents);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Scan.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);}
```

Everything works except for the "arrowS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)" line in mainactivity

1. Scan intent is started from the mainActivity class
2. MainActivity intent is started from the onActivityResult() Method in the Scan class

I don't get any error message in Logcat, but my Logcat output/App is renewed  and nothing is changed. Does anyone see where my fault lies?

Comment: What is arrowS and did u initialized it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to start scan activity and bring result back to MainActivity ? If I am right. You are making two mistakes.
 1. Check if have initialized the views scan button and arrowS.
 2. From Scan Activity you are sending just "scanContent" ->  i.putExtra("scanContent", contents); 
And in MainActivity you are checking if there is any data in "message" key which will return false . Remove this line -> if(extras.containsKey("message")); and your code will work fine

(Btw instead of startActivity(scan) you should use startActivityForResult(scan) and handle result in onActivityResult() of MainActivity)